# Replace() command throwing Field Length error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I am trying to execute the below statement:

```
  update dbo.CaseTable
  set Quick=REPLACE(Quick, 
    "Case files have been archived.  To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.  Case files have been archived.  To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.", 
    "Case files have been archived.  To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.")
```

and I get the below error:

> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 2
>   The identifier that starts with 'Case files have been archived.  To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.  Case file' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

How can I do a replace on this string if it's too long?

Comment: Have you checked the data structure? Are you sure the string is not truncated? What is the type of Quick?

Comment: Quick is ntext, so I think it's large enough?

Answer (score 1):

You have used double quotes for the replace string, use single quote. Below query should work fine. Basically, the text provided within double quote is considered as column name.

```
set Quick=REPLACE(Quick, 'Case files have been archived. To have file access        restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name. Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.', 'Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.')
```

As sql does not allow replace for ntext type, use the below  query.

```
Quick = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Quick as NVarchar(MAX)), 'Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name. Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.', 'Case files have been archived. To have file access restored, please enter a helpdesk ticket with the full case name.') AS NText)
```

Comment: When I run with single quotes, I get:

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: Try using the above mentioned updated query, SQL Replace does not allow Replace on Ntext, instead you could cast it >> Replace the content >> and then again cast it back to ntext